# Hidden element won't copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add button to copy simple text string but without success.

```js
function kopiraj() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("toCopy");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  document.getElementById("telefon").innerHTML = 'Copied';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="kopiraj()">Copy</button>
<input type="hidden" id="toCopy" value="123456789">
<p id="telefon"></p>
```

It does not put anything in Clipboard.

I do not need input field. I can add text in JS itself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of the `hidden` attribute, use an offscreen class and the `aria-hidden` attribute (the latter for accessibility):

```
.offscreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}

<input ... class="offscreen" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't `.select()` a hidden element that has `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;` but you can do something like this:

```js
function kopiraj() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("toCopy");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```css
[aria-hidden="true"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9999;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="kopiraj()">Copy</button>
<input type="text" id="toCopy" value="123456789" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Good solution, but styling `aria-hidden` across the board seems a bit dangerous. Plenty of other page elements might be hidden for screen readers but intended to be visible for others.

Comment: @isherwood that's fair. I was originally going to use `#toCopy` for the selector but then I noticed your solution posted shortly before mine, so I changed the selector to something that might want to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select a hidden element.

Best way is to copy the value in the element to another visible element.

As you can see, I created a `textarea` with an absolute position and set the top and left to -9999px. So now, you can copy the value in the `hidden element` to the `textarea` and then cope the value in the `textarea` to the clipboard

```js
function kopiraj() {
  var copyFrom = document.getElementById("toCopy"); //Value to copy
  var copyTo  = document.getElementById("valueToCopy"); //Visible element to copy the value to
  
  copyTo.value = copyFrom.value; //Fill the visible element with the value to copy 
  copyTo.select(); //Select the value
  document.execCommand("Copy"); //Copy
  copyTo.value = ""; //Empty the visible element after copy
}
```

```css
.valueToCopy{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="valueToCopy" id="valueToCopy"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="kopiraj()">Copy</button>
<input type="hidden" id="toCopy" value="123456789">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used this JavaScript code which doesn't require any new HTML elements:

```
var text = ...;
var listener = function(ev) {
    ev.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", text);
    ev.preventDefault();
};
document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
document.execCommand("copy");
document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
```

Comment: Works fine on Chromium browsers